# How to set ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin in the path?

Tags: contract-development

I want to develop smart contracts and started from scratch and i couldn't find a solution to set my CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/bin environment path!

Comment: Probably a better place for this question is stack overflow, on which there might have already been an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840482/cmake-install-prefix-environment-variable-doesnt-work . Not sure what you are trying to achieve: if you want the output directory to be in the operation system's path variable, you will have to manually add it; or if you want to set CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX for your cmake build, you will have to either use "set" in your cmake file, or "-D" option in your cmake command.

Answer (score 1):

If `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is set (check with `echo $CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`), then you would add

```
[[ -d $CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIXPATH ]] && PATH="$PATH:$CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/bin"
```

to one of your start up files (bashrc/zshrc).